# Can I withdraw Ether from exchanges to a contract wallet?

Tags: transactions, wallets, exchanges

I was making a withdraw from Bittrex to a contract wallet. I never received the ether.

On the [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb83dbd802c1fa90f1dcd1f7815b6f477b99c3a5915da2df04abfeae2633487fa) it says:

> "Warning! An error occurred during contract execution"

Is there a way to resolve this? How to access the funds?

Can't I withdraw Ether from exchanges to a contract wallet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that it requires more gas (i.e. Higher transaction fee) than for sending to an account. Most likely the exchanges wallet is not providing enough gas when it makes the transaction so it fails.  It of course can be done but you would need to contact the exchange to get them to allow a higher max gas on each transaction. It's still less than 2 cents.

Answer (score 2):

Since Bittrex displays the value of the currencies in pairs I suppose they are basically a Forex. If so, you probably don't know how Forex works since you do not receive any of the currency you buy. You bet on a pair (USD-ETH, XBT-USD...), you capitalize on the appreciation/depreciation (you can actually make money on the USD depreciating) and then cash out in your original currency. You can start you research [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo4z26THnpo).

Comment: Bittrex is no exchange anymore? I don't see how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

If your smart contract has a "**receive function**", you can deposit it. First, check whether the "**receive function**" exists in the source code of the contract.

```
receive() external payable {}
```

If you cannot access the source code of the contract, enter the address of your contract in the transfer section from Metamask wallet. If metamask does not allow transfer, the contract is closed to depositing ether.